# How to use ng-repeat with <tr> tag?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a data model like this:

```
$scope.meals = [
    {
        name: 'breakfast',
        days: [
            {
                name: 'monday'
            },
            {
                name: 'sunday'
            }            
        ]
    },
    {
        name: 'lunch',
        days: [
            {
                name: 'saturday'
            },
            {
                name: 'sunday'
            }            
        ]
    },   
    {
        name: 'dinner',
        days: [
            {
                name: 'friday'
            }           
        ]
    }      
];
```

I want to generate `<tr>`'s for all options in object, like this:

```
<tr>
    <td>breakfast - monday</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>breakfast - sunday</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>lunch - saturday</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>lunch - sunday</td>
</tr>
```

etc.

How can I do this? Nesting `<tr>` is impossible and I do not have an idea about how to use `ng-repeat`.

Answer (score 1):

You can do with `ng-repeat-start` and `ng-repeat` : but there are will be epmty `tr` tags

```
<table >
  <tr ng-repeat-start="meal in meals" ng-if="meal.close"></tr>
  <tr ng-repeat-end ng-repeat="day in meal.days">
      <td>{{meal.name}} - {{day.name}}</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use template/tbody tag and you will not have to change your data structure at all:

Example: In Angular2 u can use

```
<template ngFor #meal [ngForOf]="meals">
  <tr ngFor="#day of meal.days">
    <td>{{ meal.name }} - {{ day }}</td>
  </tr>
</template>
```

Example: In Angular1 :(AFAIK, it is okay to have multiple `<tbody>`'s in a single table.)

```
<tbody ng-repeat="meal in meals">
  <tr ng-repeat="day in meal.days">
    <td>{{ meal.name }} - {{ day }}</td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your data structure is no good for `ng-repeat`

first of all, adapt it:

```
$scope.mealsList = $scope.meals.reduce(function(mealArray, meal) {
  meal.days.forEach(function (day) {
    mealArray.push({ name: meal.name, day: day.name });
  });
  return mealArray;
}, []);
// result:
// [{name: 'breakfast', day: 'monday' }, {name:'breakfast', day:'monday' }...]
```

Then use ng-repeat as classic inside the template:

```
<tr ng-repeat="meal in mealsList">
  <td>{{ meal.name }} - {{ meal.day }}</td>
</tr>
```

What would happen is that - if you edit your original data model, you won't see changes in the adapted data model.

You can circumvent in this way:

```
<button ng-click="addMeal()">Add Another meal</button>
```

Then inside your controller:

```
function addMeal() {
  $scope.meals.push({}); // add data in your own way
  $scope.mealsList = adaptMeals($scope.meals);
}
```

This would re-build the `mealsArray` each time a new meal is added, and it's perfectly fine to do, except if your meal array contains 50.000+ elements ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can format the array as you want using `forEach` as below and use the same with `ng-repeat`

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('TestController', function($scope) {
  var mealsData = [
    {
        name: 'breakfast',
        days: [
            {
                name: 'monday'
            },
            {
                name: 'sunday'
            }            
        ]
    },
    {
        name: 'lunch',
        days: [
            {
                name: 'saturday'
            },
            {
                name: 'sunday'
            }            
        ]
    },   
    {
        name: 'dinner',
        days: [
            {
                name: 'friday'
            }           
        ]
    }      
];
  
  var meals = [];
  
  mealsData.forEach(function(meal) {
    if(meal && meal.days) {
       meal.days.forEach(function(day) {
          meals.push({name: meal.name, day: day.name});
       });
    }
  });
  
  $scope.meals = meals;
  
});

angular.bootstrap(document, ['app']);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<table ng-controller="TestController">
  <tr ng-repeat="meal in meals">
     <td>{{meal.name + ' - ' + meal.day}}</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```